# Trying to run perl scripts with fast-cgi and lighttpd, but file just downloads

Tags: perl, fastcgi, lighttpd

The problem is my .pl script is downloaded as a blank file instead of being executed.

I read: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/ApplicationsUsingLighttpd

My dispatch.fcgi is the following: (it is located in usr/bin/

```
#!perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use CGI::Fast;
use Embed::Persistent; {
my $p = Embed::Persistent->new();
while (new CGI::Fast) {
my $filename = $ENV{SCRIPT_FILENAME};
my $package = $p->valid_package_name($filename);
my $mtime;
if ($p->cached($filename, $package, \$mtime)) {
eval {$package->handler;};
}
else {
$p->eval_file($ENV{SCRIPT_FILENAME});
}
}
}
```

This is my code in my lighttpd config file:

```
".pl" =>
((
"fastcgi.debug" => 1,
"bin-path" => "/usr/bin/dispatch.fcgi",
"socket" => "/tmp/fcgi.socket",
"check-local" => "disable",
"min-procs" => 1,
"max-procs" => 5,
"idle-timeout" => 20
))
```

I had to install CGI.pm and the cpan module embed.
Now I do not get any errors in my server log, but as I said, the script just downloads.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: 'The' script being which, the dispatch.pl script or the script you're trying to run from it?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are not sending the correct headers. Use the "header" function in the CGI module to emit the headers

```
$cgi = new CGI;
$cgi->header();
```

Then you should be good to go.

For more information check out the header documentation:

http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LDS/CGI.pm-3.43/cgi_docs.html#header

Comment: print $cgi->header; - it doesn't output by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Have carp write to a file and look there for problems.

```
BEGIN {
use CGI::Carp qw/carpout/;
open LOG, ">>", "carp.log" or die("Cannot open file: $!\n");
carpout(LOG);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure static exclude is set for the extensions. Something like...

static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl" )

Or it will just download the file like any other.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $cgi = new CGI;
print $cgi->header();
print 'Hello world.';
```

works! But, I am wondering why I need to print the headers to get it to work with fastcgi and lighttpd. I have a large script someone else wrote that works on my apache and regular cgi server. I guess I have to modify it to work on my new server.

The problem is I think printing the header might mess up the script because it does something like printing html that gets executed.

Thanks again

Comment: The CGI spec requires that a header is prepended to the actual content that will be interpreted by the client.